# Could not find a declaration file for module 'hclust'

Tags: reactjs

I npm installed [this](https://github.com/greenelab/hclust) module and it is showing in the dependencies of my package.json. When I `import { clusterData } from 'hclust'`, VS code tells me `Could not find a declaration file for module 'hclust'. '/Users/danielsteman/Desktop/dev/spotify_cluster_analysis/webapp/reactTensor/node_modules/hclust/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm i --save-dev @types/hclust if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'hclust';ts(7016)`. I also tried to run `npm i --save-dev @types/hclust` but I'm getting a 404 not found error. I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @types/hclust doesn't exist, you'll need to create your own .d.ts declaration file for the hclust module.

When you do so, you may also choose to submit it to [DefinitelyTyped](https://definitelytyped.org) so that others may benefit from it.